# change of variable of $p(x) = 1/x$, to $p(y)$ where $y = 1/x$.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I have a distribution function of $x$ written as $p(x) = \frac{1}{x}$(x>0). now I want to do a change of variable. let $y = \frac{1}{x}$. My calculation gave me $p(y) = p(x) |\frac{dx}{dy}| = \frac{1}{y}$. This is not at all intuitive to me. Did I make some mistake? or my intuition is wrong.

Comment: $(x>0)$ will not be a valid support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that these are probability *density* functions, then you are nearly okay, except for the bit where you neglected to identify the support for the probability functions.

$\begin{align}p_X(x)~&=~ x^{-1} \cdot \mathbf 1_{x\in\bbox[1pt,border:solid 0.1pt pink]{\text{X-support}}}\\[1ex]Y~&=~X^{-1} \\[2ex]p_Y(y) ~&=~ \lvert\dfrac{\partial y^{-1}}{\partial y}\rvert\cdot f_X(y^{-1}) \\ &=~ \lvert\dfrac{\partial y^{-1}}{\partial y}\rvert\cdot (y^{-1})^{-1}\cdot \mathbf 1_{(y^{-1})\in\bbox[1pt,border:solid 0.1pt pink]{\text{X-support}}} \\ &=~ y^{-2}\cdot y\cdot \mathbf 1_{(y^{-1})\in\bbox[1pt,border:solid 0.1pt pink]{\text{X-support}}}
\\ &=~ y^{-1}\cdot \mathbf 1_{y\in\bbox[1pt,border:solid 0.1pt pink]{\text{Y-support}}}\end{align}$

Comment: the equations do not shown correctly from my browser.

Comment: Try now.  Changed the formatting environment.